# How to load new list in grid using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have my jquery like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable({
        title: 'Allot to Students below',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 5,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkbo.xes on first column
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("NotAllotedStudentsList")',
            //deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteStudent")',
            //updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateStudent")',
            //createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateStudent")'
        },
        fields: {
            UserNo: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '15%'
            },
            Batch: {
                title: 'Batch',
            },
            EmailAddress: {
                title: 'Email address',
            },
            ContactNo: {
                title: 'Contact No',
                type: 'textarea',
            }
        }
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable('load');

    //Assign selected students
    $('#SearchFor').button().click(function () {
        var SearchForValue = $("#NotAllotedStudentsList").val();
        var StudentInputTypeValue = $("#InputType").val();
        var options = {};
            options.type = "POST";
            options.url = "/Dashboard/NotAllotedStudentsList/";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ model: { SearchFor: SearchForValue, StudentInputType: StudentInputTypeValue } });
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            $.ajax(options);
    $('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable('load');//This shows old list,how to rewrite this?
    });
```

where,initally it displays NotAllotedStudentsGrid list, i have limited the NotAllotedStudentsGrid list using SearchForValue. But, its displays the old list. kindly tell me how to load the new list.

i have my controller like,

```
 public ActionResult NotAllotedStudentsList(AllotQuestionSet model,int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        List<TutorStudentsGridModel> tutorStudentsGridModelList = new List<TutorStudentsGridModel>();
        User userDetails = _sessionHelper.Get<User>(KrackemSessionConstants.UserDetails);
        StudentResponse studentListResponse = new StudentResponse();
        int questionSetNo = Int32.Parse(_sessionHelper.Get<string>(KrackemSessionConstants.QuestionSetNo));

        if (model.SearchFor != null && model.StudentInputType == StudentInputType.ContactNo)
        {
            StudentRequest studentRequest = new StudentRequest
            {
                TutorUserNo = userDetails.UserNo,
                QuestionSetNo = questionSetNo,
                InputString = model.SearchFor
            };

             studentListResponse = _questionSetServiceHelper.GetNotAllottedStudentsByContactNo(studentRequest);

        }
               foreach (StudentContract studentDetails in studentListResponse.StudentList)
            {
                TutorStudentsGridModel tutorStudentsGridModel = MappingEngineFactory.GetMappingEngine().Map<StudentContract, TutorStudentsGridModel>(
                    studentDetails);
                tutorStudentsGridModel.Id = studentDetails.UserNo;

                tutorStudentsGridModelList.Add(tutorStudentsGridModel);
            }

        if (jtSorting != null)
            tutorStudentsGridModelList = ControllerHelper.SortList(jtSorting, tutorStudentsGridModelList);

        tutorStudentsGridModelList = jtPageSize > 0 ? tutorStudentsGridModelList.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList() : tutorStudentsGridModelList.ToList();

        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = tutorStudentsGridModelList, TotalRecordCount = studentListResponse.StudentList.Count() });
    }
```

Comment: In your example you are making an ajax call then throwing away the returned results??? Also, is your server code really expecting a single parameter called `model` with multiple properties? Please show the server code too.

Comment: I have my controller method like,

Comment: Posted my controller code.Kindly tell me how to rewrite the code.

Comment: What does `AllotQuestionSet` look like?

Comment: AllotQuestionSet - model name.

Comment: *I meant*: What does the class look like? :)